# Update Query in Farsi

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with my query in sql server 2012

```
UPDATE STUDENTS SET نام = N'%[احسان]%' WHERE نام = N'%[علی]%';
```

I used this but result is 0 row affected . I have column `نام` and other columns with Farsi names .

Comment: I don't understand Farsi, but this seems to be a copy/paste error `SET نام = N'%[احسان]%'` When setting a new value the wildcards  % are meaningless and probably also the square brackets

Comment: Look at your `where` - this is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want `like` in the `where` clause.  And, perhaps not a `like` pattern for actually setting the value.

Perhaps:

```
UPDATE STUDENTS
    SET نام = N'احسان'
    WHERE نام LIKE N'%[علی]%';
```

Or, if you want to replace the names:

```
UPDATE STUDENTS
    SET نام = REPLACE(نام, N'[علی]', N'احسان')
    WHERE نام LIKE N'%[علی]%';
```

Comment: Maybe it is also worth to mention for Mr Arman that this query will replace all *something-Ali-something* with just *Ehsan*, and not *something-Ehsan-something* (before he executes the query :)))

Comment: @MrSimpleMind . . . Your suggestion that he really wants `replace()` is reasonable.

Comment: But this doesn't work for me :( This Change All نام column values to New value !!!!

Comment: Is it possible that all the column values contained علی?

Comment: When square brackets are used in a LIKE, it means to match any one of the characters.   For example LIKE '%[ALI]%' will match any string that contains a letter 'A', or letter 'L', or letter 'I'.    If you want to find just strings that contain 'ALI' as a substring, leave out the brackets.  LIKE '%ALI%'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a convert,

I guess you do create your table something like:

```
create table STUDENTS ( [نام] CHAR(60) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS );
```

or

```
create table STUDENTS ( [نام] CHAR(60) COLLATE Frisian_100_CI_AI );
```

See my [**sqlfiddle here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2709c/1)

```
update STUDENTS set
[نام]
= convert( text, N'احسان' collate Arabic_CI_AS)
where
[نام] 
like
convert( text, N'%علی%' collate Arabic_CI_AS)
;
```

And as I said before, this will change xALIx with just EHSAN. Not replacing the occurrences only. See comment in prev. answer.

See the sqlfiddle for two different updates, where

- one update all %ALI% to EHSAN.
- And the other which updates all ALI (not xALIx) with just EHSAN.